# MS Teams Links from Tab to Chat Channels request authorization only on Mobile App

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a teams application that uses a grid in a custom tab (user tab) to display a list of channels with certain details related to the operation of the company. The idea is that when the user of the app is interested on following one of the items in the list they click and are redirected to the "Team - Channel" that is related to that item in the list. The Teams and Channel are created dynamically by our application using MS GRAPH API in the organization where the app is installed. All this works well and we store in our own backend the details of each channel created (The url provided by the Graph API to be able to redirect users to those channels).

All this works well and in the web UI and desktop version of the app the behavior is flawless. Although when testing the mobile version of MS TEAMS with an ANDROID tablet (Galaxy Tablet with Android V 10 and MS Teams V 1416/1.0.0.2021020402) We noticed that users which are either "Owners" or "Members" of the linked channels get a message "requesting to join" the channel when they click the link in the application tab that should redirect them to the specified channel. The same users can anyways from the mobile application itself see the team and channel related to the entry in the list and select it... and chat on it... but the link from our App tab to the channel itself pops up the "Request to Join" screen.

The situation has been as well a bit erratic... sometimes the link works as expected in the mobile app and all of the sudden the app start requesting access when accessing the link. We are wondering if is related with the fact that we create the teams and channels dynamically and maybe the mobile app caches the access to the user channels creating a conflict with recently added channels... just a theory.

Any help or idea or similar experience is greatly appreciated. Our application is close to hit production and this erratic behavior might render it unusable.

Thanks!

Jorge Luna.

Comment: so ... where is your code? what did not work as expected? exactly what error text did your get back? ... _details, please!_ ... [*grin*]

Comment: how are you linking to the channels? Direct urls, or deeplinking?

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the reply... as for the details the link I am talking about is a direct link that we retrieve from the details of the channel when we create it with the application. The link looks something like this : 'https ://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3a19{SOMEGUID_CHANNEL}%40thread.tacv2/{SOME_CHANNEL_NAME}?groupId={SOME_TEAM_GROUP_ID}&tenantId={COMPANY_TENANT_ID}' ...

Comment: As far as code goes is just a regular Anchor link generated by a REACT application..... I am not sure if it will add to the equation any more since the link works as expected in web browser... and extracting the whole code to post it here is out of question for company privacy reasons (I can provide further details in a personal chat if you think that will be necessary)...  Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Hi Ivancho72, Could you please share us repro steps and screenshots

Comment: Hi Ivancho72, are you still persisting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We hope you are trying for authentication flow for tabs.
OAuth 2.0 is an open standard for authentication and authorization used by Azure Active Directory (AAD) and many other identity providers. A basic understanding of OAuth 2.0 is a prerequisite for working with authentication in Teams. For more information, see OAuth 2 simplified that is easier to follow than the formal specification. Authentication flow for tabs and bots are different because tabs are similar to websites so they can use OAuth 2.0 directly. Bots do a few things differently, but the core concepts are identical.

Could you please try the below [sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp).

If you are still facing the issue please write to [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1)